# Contains of Option[String] in Scala not working as expected?

Tags: scala

I just discovered something weird. This statement:

```
Some("test this").contains("test")
```

Evaluates to false. While this evaluates to true:

```
Some("test this").contains("test this")
```

How does this make sense? I thought the Option would run the contains on the wrapped object if possible.

**EDIT:**

I'm also thinking about this from a code readability perspective. Imagine you are seeing this code:

```
person.name.contains("Roger")
```

Must `name` be equal to Roger? Or can it contain Roger? The behavior depends if it's a String or Option[String].

Comment: _"I thought the Option would run the contains on the wrapped object if possible."_ how would that even work? No, `Option.contains` just checks if the `Option` contains the value you want. The logic you want can be expressed like this: `opt.fold(ifEmpty = false)(str => str.contains("test"))`

Comment: Alternatively to what LMMS posted, your desired logic could also be expressed like this `Some("test this").exists(_.contains("test"))`.

Comment: I ended up going with Some("test this").getOrElse("").contains("test")

Comment: Think of an `Option` as a list that can only have length 0 or 1. What would you expect `List("test this", "test that").contains("test")` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a principle in typed functional programming called "parametric reasoning".  Broadly stated, the principle is that it's desirable to be able to have intuitions about what a function does just from looking at its type signature.

If we "devirtualize" (effectively turning it into a static method... this is actually a fairly common optimization step in object-oriented runtimes) `Option`'s `contains` method has the signature:

```scala
def contains[A, A1 >: A](opt: Option[A], elem: A1): Boolean
```

That is, it takes an `Option[A]` and an `A1` (where `A1` is a supertype of `A`, if it's not an `A`) and returns a `Boolean`.  Implicitly in Scala's typesystem, of course, we know that `A` and `A1` are both subtypes of `Any`.

Without knowing anything more about what the types `A` and `A1` are (`A` might be `String` and `A1` might be `AnyRef`, or `A` and `A1` might both be `Int`: whatever our intuition, it has to apply as much in either situation), what could we possibly do?  We're basically limited to combinations of operations involving an `Option[Any]` and an `Any` which eventually get us to a `Boolean` (and, ideally, won't throw an exception).

For instance, `opt.nonEmpty && opt.get == elem` works: we can always call `nonEmpty` on an `Option[Any]` and then compare the contents using equality.  We could also do something like `opt.isEmpty || (opt.get.## % 43) == (elem.## % 57)`, but knowing that the contents of the `Option` and some other object have equal remainders in two different bases doesn't strike one as useful.

Note that in your specific case, because there's no `contains` method on an `Any`.  What should the behavior be if we have an `Option[Int]`?

It might actually be useful, since we do have the ability to convert arbitrary objects into `String`s via the `toString` method (thank you Java!), to implement a `containsSubstring` method on `Option[A]`:

```scala
def containsSubstring(substring: String): Boolean =
  nonEmpty && get.toString.contains(substring)
```

You could implement an enrichment class along these lines:

```scala
object Enrichments {
  implicit class OptionOps[A](opt: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def containsSubstring(substring: String): Boolean =
      opt.nonEmpty && opt.get.toString.contains(substring)
  }
}
```

then you only need:

```scala
import Enrichments.OptionOps

Some("test this").containsSubstring("test")  // evaluates true

case class Person(name: Option[String], age: Int)

// Option(p).containsSubstring("Roger") would also work, assuming Person doesn't override toString...
def isRoger(p: Person): Boolean = p.name.containsSubstring("Roger")
```

Comment: That's probably the best approach. That way there's no potential for confusion when reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check the docs and eventually the code of the API that you are you using. The docs detail what `Option`'s [contains](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#contains%5BA1%3E:A%5D(elem:A1):Boolean) does and how it works:

```
  /** Tests whether the option contains a given value as an element.
   *
   * This is equivalent to:
   * 
   * option match {
   *   case Some(x) => x == elem
   *   case None    => false
   * }
   * 
   *  // Returns true because Some instance contains string "something" which equals "something".
   *  Some("something") contains "something"
   *
   *  // Returns false because "something" != "anything".
   *  Some("something") contains "anything"
   *
   *  // Returns false when method called on None.
   *  None contains "anything"
   *
   *  @param elem the element to test.
   *  @return `true` if the option has an element that is equal (as
   *  determined by `==`) to `elem`, `false` otherwise.
   */
  final def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean =
    !isEmpty && this.get == elem
```

Comment: I did, and none of those examples refers to what I mentioned above (the String concept of contains). However, I missed the return part that says "if the option has an element that is equal (as determined by `==`) to `elem`, `false` otherwise."

Comment: It also said on the first line that `contains` is equivalent to `option match { case Some(x) => x == elem ; case None => false }`. You probably missed that too.